# Struggling to understand "categories equivalence" definition. SOS.

Tags: category-theory, definition

So let $F: \mathcal {A} \mapsto \mathcal{B}, G: \mathcal {B} \mapsto \mathcal{A}$ be two functors. Clearly, those can be understood as morphisms of the $\mathbb{CAT}$ - category of all categories.

My textbook says that $G \circ F = 1_{\mathcal{A}}, F \circ G = 1_{\mathcal{B}}$ is unreasonably strict, much less useful definition. Even though my current knowledge is not sufficient to understand "unreasonable strictness", I trust it. Right after textbook proudly says that following definition is far better: 
$$G \circ F \cong 1_{\mathcal{A}}, F \circ G \cong 1_{\mathcal{B}}$$

And that's the point where I get completely stuck.
Obviously, $G \circ F$ is a map in the $\mathbb{CAT}$; therefore, it is a functor (I guess there is something else here - it is always endofunctor: it maps category to itself; not sure whether this fact is important). But **natural transformation** is the only way one able to define and measure "isomorphism between functors" (with requirements that both do have same domain and codomain, which is met here). **However, natural transformation does not live in the $\mathbb{CAT}$, it lives in an appropriate "functor category", where functors are objects rather than morphisms**. I don't quite understand such a "mental jump" from the $\mathbb{CAT}$ to a something completely different.

So in order to figure it out, I try to draw a simplest possible schema. 
$$(G \circ F): \mathcal{A} \mapsto \mathcal{A}$$ $$1_{\mathcal{A}}: \mathcal{A} \mapsto \mathcal{A}$$ $$\lambda: (G \circ F) \mapsto 1_{\mathcal{A}}$$ 
$$\forall X \in \mathcal{A}: \lambda_X \text{ is an isomorphism ... WITH WHAT?! }$$
Last statement blows my head off! $\lambda_X$ is a morphism from a $((G \circ F)X)$ to a $((1_{\mathcal{A}})X)$. Does it require those two to be isomorphic in a regular sense?

Kindly asking someone smart to explain what am I missing here avoiding sophisticated examples from other branches of mathematics?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Avoiding examples of *what* other branches of mathematics?  What branches can we use?

Comment: @Randall, I am fine with combinatorics, for example. Something like monoids, groups, etc. gonna work as well. But definitely not vector spaces which I am afraid of ;) Purely abstract example (hopefully) will work as well!

Comment: The best example is in vector spaces (my opinion).  What's wrong with them if you're okay with groups?

Comment: The best way to understand this stuff is through concrete examples, not abstract ones.  But, here's the best abstract exercise for this:  prove that any category is equivalent to any of its skeleta, then find examples to show they need not be iso.  (the last bit is easy.)

Comment: Categories have skeletons which are special subcategories. Full subcategories such that for every object there is exactly one isomorphic object in the skeleton. Two different skeletons of categories are always isomorphic. Are you familiar with them? In for instance category set the cardinal numbers form a skeleton. Helpful  might be the fact that two categories are equivalent if and only if their skeletons are isomorphic. Then the new issue "equivalence" is defined by means of the old issue "isomorphic". Helped me a lot to understand equivalences.

Comment: There's nothing weird going on about where the natural transformations "live." $GF$ and $id_A$ are objects of, and $\lambda$ a morphism in, the functor category $\mathcal{A}^\mathcal{A}$; and the data of the other half of the equivalence are similarly in $\mathcal{B}^\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Just to answer the question in capital letters: $\lambda_X$ is an isomorphism from  $(G\circ F)(X)$ to $1_{\mathcal A}(X)$. In other words, from $G(F(X))$ to $X$.

Comment: $\mathbf{Cat}$ is a 2-category... Natural transformations are 2-cells of this 2-category...